# Instant segue, before presenting view

Tags: swift, segue

I'm trying to figure out the correct viewcontroller/segue structure for my project and I need some help please.

When '**B**' is will be presented from '**A**', it checks if a statement is true. Only if true, '**C**' should instantly be presented instead of '**B**'. The user continues to '**D**', and from '**D**' there should be an unwind segue back to '**B**'.

[image: Segue Example]

I could check the if-statement in the `viewDidAppear()` of '**B**' but then the view would first load for a few milliseconds before loading viewcontroller '**C**'. It doesn't look nice.

If I try to make the if-statement in `viewDidLoad()`, I get an error:

*Attempting to present '**C**' on '**B**' whose view is not in the window hierarchy*

Maybe there is a better way to go about this?

Comment: Why don't to try to present `C` from `A`, When user pop uses custom transition animation. Apple may decline if you push multiple view controller without user knowledge.

Comment: This would give a very unusual user experience, couldn't you redesign the whole to get into a more common model?

Comment: I think that there is kind of ambiguous check: "it checks if a statement is true. Only if true, 'C' should instantly be presented instead of 'B'.", so why you just check it in `A` and decide whether `B` or `C` should be presented?

Comment: If viewcontroller **B** is not on the bottom of the stack, I would have to present it on top of viewcontroller **D**, and I believe it would be optimal to keep the stack to a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use segues without actually showing each ViewController that you segue to. Segues are only called after the ViewController is actually presented, you cannot segue from `viewDidLoad` for instance.

Your only option to skip a ViewController with segues is if you set up tow different segues, one in which you take the "full path", say `A->B->C` and one in which you skip `B`, `A->C`. So you need to have a segue to `C` from both `A` and `B`.

Of course using this approach you cannot use unwind segue to a ViewController that wasn't presented at all. You can fix this issue by not using unwind segues, but by setting up segues "backwards" as well. What I mean by "backward" is that you set up a segue say `D->B`, then you can go "back" to `B` even if the order of your segues was `A->C->D->B`.

Comment: I feel like it would make a very complex structure..
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTC0m.png

Comment: This is a limitation of segues due to their design. Unless you completely change your navigation to not use segues, I don't see any other way to achieve what you need in a less complex way.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a pretty neat solution at last. I added another viewcontroller which holds two container views - one embedding '**B**' and the other containing '**C**'. Which container should be shown is managed by these two simple functions:

```
func switchToB() {
    containerB.isHidden = false
    containerC.isHidden = true
}

func switchToC() {
    containerB.isHidden = true
    containerC.isHidden = false
}
```

I let '**D**' unwind to the new viewcontroller, which then triggers `switchToC()`.